# Gradle Robolectric Resources NotFoundException in Testing

Tags: android, testing, resources, gradle, robolectric

I've already knew that this issue has been asked before but I can't solve this problem. 
I am able to compile and apply test with jUnit, Robolectric and Gradle. The issue or error comes when I try to test an Activity or get a resource. Every time I've got the same issue:

**android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: unknown resource**

**Resources$NotFoundException: no such theme**

```
 PageActivity startPageActivity   =   Robolectric.buildActivity(PageActivity.class).create().get();

 Context context =  Robolectric.getShadowApplication().getApplicationContext();
 ShadowContext shadowContext = shadowOf(context);
 assertNotNull( " No App name String " ,shadowContext.getString(R.string.app_name) );
```

And this is the project's structure:

```
.
├── build.gradle
├── settings.gradle
└── mainproject
    ├── build
    │   ├── classes
    │   │   └── debug
    ├── build.gradle
    └── src
       └── main
       │    ├── AndroidManifest.xml
       │    └── java
       │         └── com...
       │    └── resources
       └── envDev
       │    └── java
       │         └── com...
       │    └── resources
       └── envQa
       │    └── java
       │          └── com...
       │    └── resources
       └── envLive
       │    └── java
       │         └── com...
       │    └── resources
       └── test
       │    └── src
       │         └── java
       │               └── com...
       │         └── rescources
       └── testEnvDev
       │    └── src
       │         └── java
       │               └── com...
       │         └── rescources
       └── testEnvQa
       │    └── src
       │         └── java
       │               └── com...
       │         └── rescources
       └── testEnvLive
            └── src
                 └── java
                       └── com...
                 └── rescources
```

This is the source set defined in gradle:

```
sourceSets {  
        main {
            java.srcDir  file('src/main/java')
            manifest.srcFile file('src/main/AndroidManifest.xml')
            res.srcDir file('src/main/resources')
        }
        envDev {
            java.srcDir file('src/envDev/java')
            manifest.srcFile 'src/envDev/AndroidManifest.xml'
            res.srcDir file('src/envDev/resources')
        }

        envQa {
            java.srcDir file('src/envQa/java')
            manifest.srcFile 'src/envQa/AndroidManifest.xml'
            res.srcDir file('src/envQa/resources')
        }

        envLive {
            java.srcDir file('src/envLive/java')
            manifest.srcFile 'src/envLive/AndroidManifest.xml'
            res.srcDir file('src/envLive/resources')
        }

        instrumentTest {
            java.srcDir  file('src/test/java')
            res.srcDir  file('src/test/resources')
        }
        instrumentTestEnvDev {
            java.srcDir file('src/testEnvDev/java')
            res.srcDir file('src/testEnvDev/resources')
        }
        instrumentTestEnvQa {
            java.srcDir file('src/testEnvQa/java')
            res.srcDir file('src/testEnvQa/resources')
        }
        instrumentTestEnvLive {
            java.srcDir file('src/testEnvLive/java')
            res.srcDir file('src/testEnvLive/resources')
        }

    }
```

Could someone give a hand to face this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using some gradle plugin to run robolectric tests? What version of robolectric are you using? No needs to specify all source sets - rename resource folders to res and just use product flavors

Comment: Yes, I'm using Gradle Android Test Plugin 0.9.1 and Robolectric 2.1. I'm going to apply again "res" as resource name again. I already did it before however it didn't work. Thanks.

Comment: Are you using android gradle plugin?

Comment: Yes, I am using the Jake Wharton one:  [link](https://github.com/JakeWharton/gradle-android-test-plugin) @EugenMrtynov

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end I managed to solve it moving to Robolectric v2.3-SNAPSHOT.

You can find this SNAPSHOT here  [oss.sonatype.org/index.html#nexus-search;quick~org.robolectric](https://oss.sonatype.org/index.html#nexus-search;quick~org.robolectric)

The same Jake Wharton plugin works well with this Robolectric v2.3-SNAPSHOT.

Perhaps this information might help someone else.

Comment: how do you add the snapshot version to your `gradle.build`? Mine can't seem to find it

Answer (score 13):

I had this same problem even with Robolectric v2.3-SNAPSHOT.  Solved it by explicitly setting the manifest in the test file via the Config annotation, like

```
@Config(manifest = "src/main/AndroidManifest.xml")
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
public class MainActivityTest extends AndroidTestCase {
...
}
```