# "android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException:" in Robolectric test

Tags: android, unit-testing, robolectric

How do I fix I the above error in this Robolectric test? Note that I am running my test in Android Studio Beta 0.8.2. I found Gradle Robolectric Resources NotFoundException in Testing which indicates that I need to specify the AndroidManifest with the `@Config` annotation. However, Android Studio generates the final the manifest by merging the ones from a build type with `main`. So what other suggestions are there to fix this error?

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
public class MainActivityTest {

    private MainActivity mActivity;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        mActivity = Robolectric.buildActivity(MainActivity.class).create().visible().get();
    }

    @Test
    public void testActivityNotNull() {
        assertThat(mActivity).isNotNull();
    }

    @Test
    public void testBaseballCardDetails() {
        FragmentManager fm = mActivity.getSupportFragmentManager();
        Fragment fragment = fm.findFragmentByTag(FragmentTags.EDIT_CARD);

        assertThat(fragment).isNotNull().isAdded().isVisible();
    }

}
```

Stack Trace:

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f0d0002
    at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1118)
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2304)
    at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:934)
    at android.support.v7.internal.view.SupportMenuInflater.inflate(SupportMenuInflater.java:115)
    at bbct.android.common.activity.MainActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(MainActivity.java:84)
```

Code where exception is thrown:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    this.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu); // Line 84

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Gradle Robolectric Resources NotFoundException in Testing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21186622/gradle-robolectric-resources-notfoundexception-in-testing)

Answer (score 1):

This is a [known problem](https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/898) and also affects `ActionBarSherlock`. You can try to use **sneuberger-amazon**'s soltion from that Github issue:

> This occurs with the appcompat-v7 ActionBar as well.
>
> The problem is that Robolectric provides a ShadowMenuInflater, but it
>   does not provide a ShadowSupportMenuInflater (which is what appcompat
>   uses).
>
> You can fix this by creating a
>   org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowSupportMenuInflater class with contents:

```
package org.robolectric.shadows;

import org.robolectric.annotation.Implementation;
import org.robolectric.annotation.Implements;

import android.support.v7.internal.view.SupportMenuInflater;
import android.view.Menu;

@Implements(SupportMenuInflater.class)
public class ShadowSupportMenuInflater extends ShadowMenuInflater {
    @Implementation
    public void inflate(int menuRes, Menu menu) {
        super.inflate(menuRes, menu);
    }
}
```

> Put this class in your own project's org.robolectric.shadows package.
>   That way Robolectric will find it when looking for a shadow for
>   SupportMenuInflater, so that all your tests will get it automatically
>   (no need to add a shadow Config to every test).

Alternatively/additionally, you can try setting `@Config(qualifiers = "v10")` in your test class.